# Why wont else condition work on Python If-else statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

The code:

```
#Loop to conduct program. User input required for each option. 

count = 1
while count == 1:
    score = input("Enter Test Score: ")
    if (score >= 90) and (score <= 100):
        print "A"
    elif (score >= 80) and (score <= 89):
        print "B"
    elif (score >= 70) and (score <= 79):
        print "C"
    elif (score >= 60) and (score <= 69):
        print "D"
    elif (score <= 59):
        print "F"
    elif (score == quit):
        print "Program Finsihed. Goodbye."
        count = 0 #Count to end loop      
    else:
        print "Please enter valid response."
```

All other conditions work, however, if something typed it does not meet the parameters, the code is supposed to prompt them again (which is what the while loop is for). However, an error arises whenever a string that does not match the parameters is attempted.

Comment: You should put the code in the question. All links eventually rot.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `input`. `input` on Python 2 tries to evaluate the input as a Python expression, so if you type something like `fhqwhgads`, Python thinks that's supposed to be Python code and throws an error because there's no `fhqwhgads` variable.

Use `raw_input`, which gives you the input as a string. You can then perform string operations on it, or (try to) convert it to an integer and handle the exception if the conversion fails:

```
while True:
    user_input = raw_input("Enter Test Score: ")
    if user_input == 'quit':
        print "Program Finsihed. Goodbye."
        break

    try:
        score = int(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter valid response."
        continue

    if 90 <= score <= 100:
        print "A"
    elif 80 <= score < 90:
        ...
```

Incidentally, `quit` is one of the few choices you could have made for your "we're done here" option that wouldn't have caused an error with your original code, because there's (usually) an actual `quit` object for that to resolve to when `input` tries to treat it as Python code.

Answer (score 1):

There were many problems with your code. I think it would be much easier to see and resolve the issues if you break your code down into functional units. I made two functions: `get_score` deals with prompting the user for input and `score_to_grade` converts a number score into a letter score. Doing this makes the code much more readable and easier to refactor, debug, etc. in the future.

```
def get_score():
    while True:
        user_in = raw_input("Enter Test Score: ")
        try:
            return float(user_in)
        except ValueError:
            if user_in == "quit":
                print "Program Finished. Goodbye."
                raise SystemExit
            print "Please enter valid response."

def score_to_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif score >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif score >= 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

while True:
    print score_to_grade(get_score())
```

Answer (score 0):

`quit` needs to be in quotes, since it is a string, not a variable:

```
...
elif (score == "quit")
...
```

Comment: the quit actually works great. Its the else that wont execute. If I type in quit in the input, then the program ends successfully. If I add quotations to the quit, then the else will work, telling me to add a valid response and the program does not terminate.

Comment: well if you type anything other than a number, it quits, right? i think what may be happening is that once python evaluates `quit', it quits from the loop, rather than actually checking if you entered "quit".

Comment: but isn't that only of the 'quit' condition is met then it will terminate?

Comment: sorry I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. have you tried the edit I suggested in my answer? does the problem remain?

Comment: If I add quotations to the quit, then the 'else' will work, telling me to add a valid response but the program does not terminate. So it does not recognize the string 'quit'.